# Bazel action graph middleman mnemonic in actions

Tags: bazel

I am using Bazel action graph to see what happens behind the scenes. I am using V1 (analysis.proto) and the graph seems complete and everything makes sense except for actions with "Middleman" `mnemonic`. I have looked everywhere and there is no mention of this `mnemonic`. The `mnemonic` itself is very strange because it does not do anything concrete. I have pasted a version of the graph below:

```
artifacts {
  id: "0"
  exec_path: "bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/internal/_middlemen/_S_Smain_Chello-greet-BazelCppSemantics_build_arch_k8-fastbuild"
}
artifacts {
  id: "1"
  exec_path: "bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/internal/_middlemen/_S_Smain_Chello-world-BazelCppSemantics_build_arch_k8-fastbuild"
}
actions {
  target_id: "0"
  action_key: "db9e25a4399752c6f2173101cef156d8cc65052294fbaae629f895aa7120c672"
  mnemonic: "Middleman"
  configuration_id: "0"
  input_dep_set_ids: "0"
  output_ids: "1"
}
```

In the action, the input and output point to the same file. What does "Middleman" `mnemonic` do and in general what is the purpose of `mnemonic` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All actions have a [mnemonic](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/glossary.html#mnemonic), which is a type of categorization.

Middlemen are special actions internally generated by Bazel. A middleman action does nothing but force its inputs to be built.